# How do I limit multi-select options for one field based on data entered into another field when they both reference the IDs of another table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables, we'll call them T1 and T2. T1 currently has nearly 600 records in it, one of which contains the ID number and another of which contains a title, so ID and TITLE:

```
T1
ID   | TITLE
-----|----------
1    | Title ABC
...  | ...
201  | Title XYZ
...  | ...
411  | Title 123
```

T2 has an ID field, a Titles field, an Accepted Titles field, and a Rejected Titles field, so ID, TITLES, ACCEPTED TITLES, and REJECTED TITLES. The access form uses a multiple select ListBox to select one or more TITLES from T1, however many are required, but usually no more than ten. Once entries are made into the TITLES field of T2, which is Numeric for the record IDs corresponding to the titles selected from T1, I want a combo box for each of the ACCEPTED TITLES and REJECTED TITLES in T2 to be limited to showing only those titles that correspond to IDs entered into the TITLES field. So, if I have in the TITLES field of T2,

```
T2
ID | TITLES        | ACCEPTED TITLES  | REJECTED TITLES 
---|---------------|------------------|----------------
1  | 1, 201, 411   |                  |
```

I want the dropdown for the ComboBox to show only the titles corresponding to those IDs entered into the TITLES field. So, taking the ACCEPTED TITLES field, it might look like this:

```
T2
ID | TITLES        | ACCEPTED TITLES    | REJECTED TITLES 
---|---------------|--------------------|---------------
1  | 1, 201, 411   | | [ ] Title ABC  \/|
                     | [ ] Title XYZ   |
                     | [ ] Title 123   |
```

I'm thinking I should be able to build a SELECT WHERE IN (...) statement that I can use in the "Row Source" properties of ACCEPTED TITLES and REJECTED TITLES. Then the list would be as short as the items selected for TITLES rather than 600+ records long. This also completely eliminates the potential for erroneous input under ACCEPTED TITLES or REJECTED TITLES since those titles can only be selected from those entered under TITLES. But, I don't yet know how to build such a SELECT statement.

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm confused about what's happening in `T2.Titles`. Are these `T1.ID`s concatenated and comma delimited? why do they not each have their own record?

Comment: The T1 table is for individual works. It contains the titles of the works, along with information about each work, such as when it was finished, number of words, etc. etc. etc.

The T2 table tracks submissions to various periodicals. There is another table that contains the periodicals themselves, but that's not important for the purpose of what I'm trying to accomplish. Since most periodicals accept multiple submissions of this kind, the TITLES field of T2 has to be able to contain multiple entries.

Comment: I'm already able to select multiple titles from a ListBox for this field. But, I only want to sift through 600+ records once. When I hear back from the periodical, I want to check the titles that have been accepted and/or rejected without having to sift through all 600+ records each time. I only want to select from the titles that were submitted.

Comment: Are you trying to do this from the datasheet view of the table or via a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It's actually much simpler than I realized:

```
Public Function GetTitleIDs() As String
   Dim IDData As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim SubLookup As Variant
   Dim SelectSubmissions As String

   ' Should pull the same records and in the same order as '
   ' those found in originating Listbox '
   Set IDData = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT [Poems].[ID], [Poems].[Title] FROM Poems ORDER BY [Title];")
   SubLookup = IDData.GetRows

   ' Submissions is the name of my originating Listbox. The rest remains unaltered. '
   Dim listrow As Integer
   For listrow = 0 To Me.Submissions.ListCount - 1
      If Me.Submissions.Selected(listrow) = True Then
         SelectSubmissions = ", " & SubLookup(0, listrow) & SelectSubmissions
      End If
   Next
   If Len(SelectSubmissions) > 0 Then
      SelectSubmissions = Right(SelectSubmissions, Len(SelectSubmissions) - 1)
   End If

   GetTitleIDs = SelectSubmissions
End Function

Private Sub Form_Current()
   ' Needed to update existing Listbox entry or entries when record is loaded '
   ' in form. If record is new, Listbox(es) will simply contain no records. This '
   ' can source all records for the fields you want in order to show existing '
   ' Listbox entries without fail. '
   Me.Declined.RowSource = "SELECT [Poems].[ID], [Poems].[Title], [Poems].[Year Completed], [Poems].[Blog Location] FROM Poems ORDER BY [Title];"
   Me.Accepted.RowSource = "SELECT [Poems].[ID], [Poems].[Title], [Poems].[Year Completed], [Poems].[Blog Location] FROM Poems ORDER BY [Title];"
End Sub

Private Sub Declined_GotFocus()
   ' Presumably your subset selection list gets focus after '
   ' checking list entries in originating Listbox. '
   Me.Declined.RowSource = "SELECT [Poems].[ID], [Poems].[Title], [Poems].[Year Completed], [Poems].[Blog Location] FROM Poems WHERE [ID] IN (" & GetTitleIDs & ") ORDER BY [Title];"
End Sub

Private Sub Accepted_GotFocus()
   Me.Accepted.RowSource = "SELECT [Poems].[ID], [Poems].[Title], [Poems].[Year Completed], [Poems].[Blog Location] FROM Poems WHERE [ID] IN (" & GetTitleIDs & ") ORDER BY [Title];"
End Sub
```

This will show only options in Declined and Accepted that are checked under Submissions, limiting selection options to only those values of interest for these fields. It's perfect.

So long as the table and ordering is the same for both the records assigned to IDData and the ListBox you're checking against, the IDs will always line up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a slightly different design for T2 (TitleStatus).

```
Create Table [TitleStatus] ([TitleID] Number, [StatusID] Number);
Create Index TitleIDindex ON [TitleStatus] (TitleID) WITH PRIMARY;
```

Then another table to house the statuses. Something like

```
Create Table [Statuses] ([StatusID] Number, [StatusText] String);
Create Index StatusIDindex ON [Statuses] (StatusID) WITH PRIMARY;
```

(this table could be organized with one column, but either way you want to prevent statuses like 'Accepted' and 'Accepted Title' from creeping in. Then you'd have two records which are the same thing but you don't naturally know to look for both)

Then T2 (TitleStatus) will look like

```
TitleStatus
TITLEID   | STATUSID
----------|----------
1         | 1
...       | ...
201       | 1
...       | ...
411       | 1
500       | 2
```

Where `Statuses` Looks like

```
 StatusID | StatusText
 1        | Accepted
 2        | Rejected
```

You're inserts should be fairly straight forward form there.

You can get all the accepted titles like this

```
Select T1.Title, Status.StatusText
From T1
Inner join TitleStatus TS on TS.TitleID = T1.ID
Inner Join Statuses S on S.StatusID = TS.StatusID
Where S.StatusText = 'Accepted'
```

Comment: Let me digest this and see if I can figure out what you've proposed here, but after I sleep some. I appreciate your taking the time to propose this.

Comment: I thought about your feedback here and realized I couldn't use them. Then in solving another problem I came across ADODB.RecordSet (useable once the correct reference is selected in Tools->References), and realized I could make use of what I learned in solving the other problem to solve this problem as well. My sample code is posted separately and checked as the solution.